# RMAN Duplicate database errors with password file location could not be found

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rman, dataguard

Running RMAN to duplicate two Oracle 12.1.0 databases, using the below, I'm faced with an error I can't seem to find an answer too.

```
c:\rman TARGET sys/password@TEST AUXILIARY sys/password@TEST_SDBY
connected to target database: TEST (DBID=226670971)
connected to auxiliary database: TEST (not mounted)

RMAN> DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE
2> FOR STANDBY
3> FROM ACTIVE DATABASE
4> DORECOVER
5> NOFILENAMECHECK;
```

Which gives the following errors

```
rman-03002: failure of duplicate Db command
rman-05501: aborting duplication of target database
rman--5622: password file location could not be found for the auxiliary database
```

Following documents online on how to create the password file, this is what I did:

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%\database 
ORAPWD FILE=PWDTEST.ora PASSWORD=password FORCE=y
```

I copied it from the Primary to the Secondary and put it in the same directory on the Secondary server.

I can't seem to figure what I've done incorrectly as I've followed multiple guides on how to set up a primary / secondary server for a dataguard environment. Nothing I've seen on searches seem to point to anything other than make sure your password file is correct.

Comment: 164.185.* is Department Of Defense.

Comment: I'm running the RMAN from my standby, I couldn't even connect running it from my primary server. 

I'm not sure everything is complete with the listner errors I'm getting. Like just now on standby, I stopped and started lsnrctl, and it gave me an operation timed out error. So I'm not sure if my spfile is correct as well as the listener. 

This might be a bigger issue than just my RMAN connection.

Comment: It might be, I just stopped / started lsnrctl 
Service CLRExtProc has 1 instance
Instance CLRExtProc Status unknown
Service TEST_STDB_DGMGRL has 1 instance
Instance test_stby, status unknown has 1 handler 

Command completed sucessfully. 

Windows services for database and listener are started.

Comment: Don't create a password file on the standby. Copy the exact same password file from the primary to the standby.

Comment: Yes, I created it on the primary, and then copied it to the standby. 

I think something else might be wrong, because now I'm getting errors like tns listneer does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor when I just now tried to reconnect via RMAN.

Comment: On some forums, I see it's ORACLE_HOME\dbs but most windows directions are saying ORACLE_HOME\database for the password file. 

Why the change? Is it significant in where I create the original?

Comment: On Windows password file name should be `PWDORACLE_SID.ora` under `ORACLE_HOME\database`. Where `ORACLE_SID` is the SID of your standby database.

Comment: Is it enough to just rename the file to PWDTEST_STBY.ora or do I need to recreate the file? I've renamed and still get the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but can you check is there any registry key like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HomeXX\ORA_<%ORACLE_SID%>_PWFILE`? Make sure that the password file exists in the folder specified by the registry keys if such keys are are set.

Comment: I know it's quite late to response but I came to know that your instance name is mismatching. Here `AUXILIARY sys/password@TEST_SDBY` you have typed `TEST_SDBY` and in of the comments you have typed `TEST_STBY` which is causing the trouble.